# Create new column at each line using findstr csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

I didn't find anything on this website about coding this feature.

Here a part of info I have and how I want it do be done.
The date is always after the day data (like in my example)

```
Type, ID, HouseNu,TimeDepart,StartingAdress,EndingAdress, etc..
Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Nov 2 2016 12:00AM
Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Nov 3 2016 12:00AM
```

I want it this way

```
Date,Type, ID, HouseNu,TimeDepart,StartingAdress,EndingAdress, etc..
Nov 2 2016,Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Nov 2 2016,Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Nov 2 2016,Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Nov 2 2016,Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Nov 3 2016,Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Nov 3 2016,Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Nov 3 2016,Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
Nov 3 2016,Occ, 12345, 122 str xxx, 13:30, 77 Street xyz, 150 Street xyz
```

Is that possible ? I know that the "12:00AM" will never appear in my data except into the datetime. So is there a possibility to find the date below the data using findstr and add a column with this date and if the date change, the date will also change?

I don't know if I am being clear enough!? Please comment if not.
I appreciated the time you will give me about this problem.

FYI, the output was from an MS SQL database and i exported all the data using sqlcmd with a stored procedure. The argument was the date and i'm doing a "do while" on the storec procedure to get 4 days of data. The export give me a punch of useless information i removed using batch script. But I have no idea how to add a column using a findstr.

Here the code i'm using to get all these info:

```
del /q Results.csv
sqlcmd -S serveur -i C:\TA_UPS_Script\SqlScript.sql -o C:\TA_UPS_Script\Results.csv -s; -SServeur\XYZ -E
findstr /v "Changed database context to 'XYZ'." C:\TA_UPS_Script\Results.csv > C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE1.csv
findstr /v "Warning"  C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE1.csv > C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE2.csv
findstr /v "Matricule"  C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE2.csv > C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE3.csv
findstr /v /c:"--------" C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE3.csv > C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE4.csv
del /q C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE1.csv
del /q C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE2.csv
del /q C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE3.csv
del /q C:\TA_UPS_Script\Results.csv
type C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE4.csv | repl "1899-12-30 " "" L > C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE5.csv
type C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE5.csv | repl ":00.000" "" L > C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE6.csv
type C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE6.csv | repl ".000" "" L > C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE7.csv
del /q C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE4.csv
del /q C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE5.csv
del /q C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE6.csv
type C:\TA_UPS_Script\Header.csv C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE7.csv > C:\TA_UPS_Script\Results.csv
del /q C:\TA_UPS_Script\ETAPE7.csv
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: Hi @Robert, I never ask to get a complete programming code. I export all data from my SQL database using sqlcmd. here the code i used but i'm stuck when creating new column using a findstr. I looking for a way to do it.

Comment: Are the spaces behind the commas truly present in the CSV file?

Comment: Yes they are. When using sqlcmd, the argument "-s;" tell the sqlcmd to split data using the ";" symbol. Indeed i write down commas but it is semi-colons ";"

Comment: You should adapt your samples in order to reflect the actual file content! Anyway, with just a `findstr` command line your task is simply not possible, because this command can only search for strings, but not modify any! So you need something like a [tag:batch-file] for your task...

Answer (score 1):

Although you did not show any own efforts to solve your task, I decided to provide a script for that, because it does not seem quite trivial to me. So here is the code, featuring explanatory comments:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE_IN=sample.csv" & rem // (input file)
set "_FILE_OUT=con"       & rem /* (output file; must not be equal to input file!
                            rem     state `con` to output to console) */
set "_FIELD=Date" & rem // (name of prepended field to be inserted into header)
set "_SEPAR=,"    & rem // (separator character; should be the `,`)
set "$HEADER=#"   & rem /* (defines whether a header is present in the input file;
                    rem     set to empty value in case no header is there) */

rem // Redirect all data to output file once to avoid multiple file accesses:
> "%_FILE_OUT%" (
    rem // Reset index counter:
    set /A "IDX=0"
    rem // Read input file line by line:
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_FILE_IN%") do (
        rem // Check whether header is available:
        if defined $HEADER (
            rem // Current line is the header, so prepend new field name:
            echo(%_FIELD%%_SEPAR%%%L
            rem // Reset header flag to not treat any more lines as header:
            set "$HEADER="
        ) else (
            rem // Current line is not the header, so capture it:
            set "LINE=%%L"
            rem // Check whether current line is one of the non-CSV lines:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem Avoid trouble with pipe by temporarily doubling all ":
            set "LINE=!LINE:"=""!^"
            rem Avoid trouble with pipe by temporarily escaping all %:
            set "LINE=!LINE:%%=^%%!"
            (echo "!LINE!" | > nul find "%_SEPAR%") && (
                endlocal
                rem // Current line is standard CSV line, so increment index:
                set /A "IDX+=1"
                rem /* Store current line in array-like variable `ARRAY[]`;
                rem    use `for /F` loop to overcome `endlocal` barrier: */
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                for /F "delims=" %%E in ("ARRAY[!IDX!]=!LINE!") do (
                    endlocal
                    set "%%E"
                )
            ) || (
                endlocal
                rem // Current line is non-CSV line, so extract date:
                for /F "tokens=1-3" %%I in ("%%L") do (
                    rem // The first three tokens constitute the date:
                    set "LINE=%%I %%J %%K"
                )
                rem // Return all stored CSV lines, preceded by found date:
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                for /L %%K in (1,1,!IDX!) do (
                    echo(!LINE!%_SEPAR%!ARRAY[%%K]!
                )
                endlocal
                rem // Reset index counter:
                set /A "IDX=0"
            )
        )
    )
    rem /* Return remaining stored CSV lines, preceded by an empty field,
    rem    for them not to be lost in case of a badly formatted file: */
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /L %%K in (1,1,!IDX!) do (
        echo(%_SEPAR%!ARRAY[%%K]!
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Basically, this batch file buffers all lines in an array-like variable `ARRAY[]` until a non-CSV line is encountered (such containing no `,`), upon which all cached lines are output, preceded by the date portion of the non-CSV line.

This approach is supposed to be robust against all kinds of special characters appearing in the file.

Comment: Thank you for this script. I never ask for a complete script and as you say i search for a while to find how to do it and never found any suitable way to do it. I just ask what is the best way to do it. However, i set up the name of my file and the output and change the ";" as a separator. The script create the file but seems to be lock into the For loop. Any advice?

Comment: The point is you did not show anything of your work so far, which is usually expected here. Anyway, the script works for me with the sample data of your question, even when I replace `,` by `;`, so hard to tell without seeing your test data. You might check your input file 1) whether it has got Windows-style line-breaks (CR+LF), and 2) whether it is an ANSI file (not Unicode). Open it with Notepad and see how it looks like (missing line-breaks?), then open the "File»Save As..." dialog and check the "Encoding:" field...